# Como hacer para que UpdateView funcione solo con el usuario creador del post?

Tags: python, django

Estoy haciendo un proyecto, el cual tiene un app de users, y otra de posts. En la de posts quiero que cada uno se pueda editar, pero solo por el usuario creador. El codigo que hice por ahora, me permite editar otro post sin ser el usuario creador.

view.py

```
class PostEditView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

template_name = 'posts/edit.html'
model = Post
fields = ['title', 'photo', 'price', 'description']
success_url = reverse_lazy('posts:feed')
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
profile = models.ForeignKey('users.Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/photos')
description = models.TextField()
price = models.IntegerField(default='0')

created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Adjunta el código del modelo `Post` y del "usuario" que creo el post.

Comment: Adjuntado el codigo!

Comment: Acabo de publicar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo podrías hacer así:

```
from django.http import Http404

class PostEditView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'posts/edit.html'
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'photo', 'price', 'description']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts:feed')

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user == self.get_object().user:
            raise Http404()

        return super().dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Si el usuario no es el creador del post, simplemente se levanta un excepción, un error 404 específicamente.

Para mayor optimizacion, debido a que en el método `dispatch` obtenemos el objeto que se editara y de nuevo se obtiene el objeto en el método [`get`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/#get) (que es donde se crea el atributo `object`), entonces esto seria mejor hacerlo en dicho método (de esta manera evitamos ejecutar 1 consulta SQL innecesaria):

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    if not request.user == self.object.user:
        raise Http404()

    return response
```

Comment: Me funciona perfecto, pero hay alguna forma que, en vez de salir un 404, lo redireccione a un template personalizado?

Comment: Claro, solo remplaza el `raise Http404()`, por un `return redirect(...)`. Por otra parte en el método `dispatch` obtienes el objeto atraves del método `get_object`?